# Merge pipeline runs before commit pipeline finishes yet explicit need breaks

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have the following stages:

```
stages:
  - lint
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy
  - cleanup
```

where the release and deploy runs only after merge-request, aka merge-request-pipeline:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

The problem is that if the merge-request pipeline fails, and I push a new commit to fix it, the merge request pipeline starts running before the build has finished in the commit pipeline (see figure below), as is `release` runs before `test`.
[image]

However, when I tried to explicitly tell gitlab, `test` is needed it tells me:

> 'release' job needs 'test' job, but 'test' is not in any previous stage
> When I used in `release` the following:

```
needed:
needs:
   - test
```

What is the solution?

Enclosed the full pipeline

[details="script"]

```
default:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind

stages:
  - lint
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy
  - cleanup

lint:
  image: python:3.10-slim
  stage: lint
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
    - echo "Linting..."
    - pip install pre-commit
    - pre-commit run --all-files

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Building Docker Image..."
    - docker compose pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker compose build builder
    - echo "Pushing Docker Image to Registry..."
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  needs:
    - lint
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Running Tests..."
    - docker compose run test
  needs:
    - build

cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Cleaning up Docker Image from Registry (if tests failed)..."
    - |
      echo "Test results: $CI_JOB_STATUS"
      if [ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" == "failed" ]; then
        docker rmi $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA || true
      fi

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - echo CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA = $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA    = $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA
    - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Tagging Image as Latest..."
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  needs:
    - test

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Production..."
    - echo "DEPLOY_USER = $DEPLOY_USER"
    - echo "DEPLOY_SERVER = $DEPLOY_SERVER"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh  # Create the .ssh directory if it doesn't exist
    - echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan $DEPLOY_SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo Materialize docker-compose.yml
    - apk add gettext
    - envsubst < docker-compose.yml > docker-compose-materialized.yml
    - echo "Copying Docker Compose file to remote server..."
    - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ./docker-compose-materialized.yml $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER:~/docker-compose.yml
    - echo "Logging in to Docker Registry $CI_REGISTRY on Remote Server..."
    - ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER "echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY"
    - echo "Pulling Docker Image..."
    - ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER "export VAR=value && docker compose pull"
    - echo "Starting new Docker container..."
    - ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER "docker compose up -d app"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

[/details]

Comment: It's hard to correlate your screenshot with your pipeline definition. Can you share (by text) which pipeline execution contain which jobs? For instance I don't understand how you can have a MR pipeline with only two stages when your build definition has at least 4 stages and 6 in the case of a MR.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering to your main issue but I think you've got at least one issue in your pipeline definition.

> where the release and deploy runs only after merge-request, aka merge-request-pipeline

Do you intend to run these jobs once the MR is merged?

I think you've got a misunderstanding about the [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword: once a rule match, the job is executed.

In your case:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Is the same as saying the job will execute if:

- it's a MR pipeline
- **OR** the commit branch is the default branch

I think you meant to have a **AND**, isn't it?

If so, you need to combine both conditions in a single rule:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

---

Then, do you really need to have a pipeline run on both the commit and the MR triggers?

You may want to control when your whole pipeline runs thanks to [`workflow`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow).